# html 5 nav tag is stop ajax in cakephp in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am using html5 structrure in cake php.
When I m using `nav` tag, the ajax links is not working, but when I replaced `nav` tag with `div` tag, the ajax links is working.

Is there any proper solution to run ajax links using `nav` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE7 won't recognize the nav tag (or other html5-only elements) without a shim. The most popular solution I'm aware of is html5shiv:

https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv

If you'd like to read more about it, you can do that here:

http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

Comment: The probelm has been resolved when i add html5 shim.js, simple is that. but to figure out this it took lot of time. :(